# Why is there spacing between my location label and temperature label

Tags: python, pyqt6

[image]I am creating a widget that shows you weather conditions. Inside the QFrame, there is a temperature label and a location label. However, there is a lot of space between them, which I want to reduce.

This is the code you need:

weather_widget:

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QVBoxLayout, QSpacerItem, QSizePolicy, QWidget, QMainWindow, QFrame, QApplication, QGridLayout, QLabel
from PyQt6.QtGui import QFont
import sys
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt


class WeatherWidget(QFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        # Set the widget properties
        self.setFixedSize(250, 150)
        
        # Create a QVBoxLayout for the widget
        self.layout = QGridLayout(self)
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.layout.setSpacing(self)

        
        
        #create temperature and location label
        self.temp_label = QLabel(self)
        self.temp_label.setStyleSheet("margin: 0; padding: 0;")

        font = QFont('Varela Round', 20, 40)
        self.temp_label.setFont(font)
        self.temp_label.setText(‘25C’)
        print('Loaded temperature:', ,25C’)

        self.location_label = QLabel(self)
        self.location_label.setFont(font)
        self.location_label.setText(’City’)
        self.location_label.setStyleSheet("margin: 0; padding: 0;")

        self.layout.addWidget(self.location_label, 0, 0, alignment=Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignTop | Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignLeft)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.temp_label, 1, 0, alignment=Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignTop | Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignLeft)

        
        self.setObjectName("WeatherWidgetFrame")
        self.setStyleSheet("""
            #WeatherWidgetFrame {
                border: 2px solid black;
                border-radius: 10px;
                padding: 10px;
                background-color: #87CEEB;
            }
        """)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    main_window = QMainWindow()  # Main window for the demo application
    widget = WeatherWidget()
    main_widget = QWidget()

    main_window.setCentralWidget(main_widget)  # Set the WeatherWidget as the central widget of the window
    main_window.resize(450, 450)
    main_layout = QVBoxLayout(main_widget)
    main_layout.addWidget(widget, alignment=Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
    main_window.show()
    main_window.raise_()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

I tried setting the content margins to 0:
self.layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
expecting there to be no space between the widgets but that didn't work, so I set the spacing to 0 as well:
self.layout.setSpacing(0)
but that didnt change things ethier. Then I tried to set the margins and padding of the two labels:

```
self.temp_label = QLabel(self)
        self.temp_label.setStyleSheet("margin: 0;     padding: 0;")

    font = QFont('Varela Round', 20, 40)
    self.temp_label.setFont(font)
    self.temp_label.setText(str(ctemp))
    print('Loaded temperature:', ctemp)

    self.location_label = QLabel(self)
    self.location_label.setFont(font)
    self.location_label.setText(location)
        self.location_label.setStyleSheet("margin: 0;     padding: 0;")
```

that didnt work ethier.`

Comment: I suppose that your issue is about the second label being aligned right below the horizontal center. This is caused by the fact that the alignment of widgets used when adding them to layouts only indicates whether the item should be specifically aligned within the *layout item cell*. Since you declared a fixed height for the WeatherWidget, the layout (based on equal size policies of the label) will split the available vertical space in two, with each "cell" being 75 pixel tall, then the labels will be aligned on top-left of those cells within the widget. The simple solution may be to reduce »

Comment: » the fixed height of the widget, but I'm afraid that this will only be a temporary workaround, with further problems raising as soon as you'll eventually add more widgets to the layout. It would help to know what that widget will eventually contain (and how spacing would be managed then), in order to provide a more insightful guidance about layout aspects. Note that Qt Style Sheets have very limited influence over the layout management: while QSS *do* take most principles from CSS, they only deal with *inner aspects* of each widget, and they have almost no influence on the overall layout.

Comment: It will eventually contain an image for the weather conditions (e.g cloud for cloudy, sun for sunny) and that is it really

Comment: Then, where should that image appear? And what would be the relation of its geometry against that of the other widgets? Proper layout requires to know where objects should (or would eventually) be placed: right now you're asking (to us as to yourself) about an issue that will *change* as soon as you add another element to the layout, and depending on its aspects (position relative to the labels, alignment of the label group, etc.). You can only do proper layout management as long as you are aware of all elements (and their requirements), **or** you have proper knowledge of how layouts work.

Comment: For example, let's suppose you want to display the labels on the left and the image on the right, with the labels *possibly* aligned on top in case the image takes more space. Still, there are some important aspects you should consider (like user font, or system font scaling) that could result in the labels requiring more vertical space than the image. You have to consider the whole layout and all its related aspects, while right now you're fixating on the spacing between labels that may (or may not) be that relevant depending on the other elements.

Comment: In my example above, for instance, you should use *nested* layouts: a "main" horizontal layout, that will have a vertical layout on the left for the labels, and the image on the right. In that case, calling the left layout's `setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)` might suffice. Since layouts always use rectangular geometries and logical placements, you can only achieve proper alignment as long as you are aware of aspects of each element, related to the other. I strongly suggest you to do some experiments with Qt Designer and play a bit with widget/layout size hints and policies.

Comment: Ok! I will try and code that today

Comment: For better clarity, I’ve added a gui design (I know it’s in black and white; I do this on my kindle) to show the design I’m trying to get